# Map Annotations not show in ios10

Tags: ios10

In iOS7, iOS8, iOS9 Map screen show custom Annotations, but I run app in iOS10 Map Annotations not shown.

I don't understand difference Map Annotations in iOS10 vs iOS7,8,9

Answer (score 1):

I went in similar problem using MKpinAnnotationView.
Anyway for iOS10/swift this code works for images:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let Identifier = "CAR"
    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?

    if let dequeued = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: Identifier) {
        annotationView = dequeued
    }
    else {
        let av = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: Identifier)
        annotationView = av
    }

    annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "Audia4")
    annotationView!.canShowCallout  = true

    return annotationView
}
```

If You want customise image: (suppose You have a Car classe that obeys to MKannotation Protocol):

```
    if let car = annotation as? Car{
        let img = car.image
        annotationView.image = img
    }else{
        annotationView.image = nil // clear it.
    }
```

where "Car" is:

```
class Car: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var lat: CLLocationDegrees?
    var long: CLLocationDegrees?
    var T: String?
    var subT: String?
    var imgName: String?
...
    init(lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees,
         title T: String, subtitle ST: String, imgName: String ) {
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.T = T
        self.subT = ST
        self.imgName = imgName

    }

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        let coords = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)
        return coords
    }

    var title : String? {
        return T
 }
    var subtitle: String? {
        return subT
 }

    var image: UIImage? {
        let img = UIImage(named: self.imgName!)
        return img
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this myself. My custom subclass of `MKAnnotationView` relied on some initialization done in my override of `initWithFrame:` and up to iOS 10, initializing the annotationView by calling `initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:` would eventually call down into initWithFrame:. Starting in iOS 10, though, `initWithFrame:` is never called. The result of this was that my custom annotations had a frame of `(0, 0, 0, 0)` and did not display. Adding

```
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, someWidth, someHeight];
```

inside `initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:` made the annotations appear again under iOS10.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem – custom annotation images did not show up on iOS 10, but worked on versions before.

For me the problem was that I used a `MKPinAnnotationView`.

Switching from:

```
pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:pinid];
pin.image = image;
```

to

```
pin = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:pinid];
pin.image = image;
```

the custom image was displayed again on iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, MKPinAnnotationView doesn't appear to work in iOS10. You need to change your MKPinAnnotationViews into MKAnnotationViews, which had zero problems for me just switching them. 
Example Swift code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var view: MKAnnotationView
    view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    view.canShowCallout = true
    view.frame = mapView.frame
    view.image = UIImage(named: "<nameHere>")
    return view
    }
```